# MomentJS Formatting with ".from"

Tags: jquery, momentjs

How can I format the value '.from' return?

[JSFiddle DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/ykbub1vb/)

```
var now = moment.utc();
var eventStart = moment.utc().day(2).hour(9).minute(00).second(00).millisecond(00);
var eventStartFormat = eventStart.diff(now, "hh:mm:ss");
```

Answer (score 0):

[`.from`](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/from/) returns a humanized string that can't be formatted.

[`.diff`](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/difference/) returns milliseconds. You can *sort of* format them by putting them into a [duration](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/durations/):

```js
var diff = moment.duration(start.diff(end));
diff.days();
diff.minutes();
//etc
```

There isn't any `.format` for durations though. See [this plugin](https://github.com/jsmreese/moment-duration-format) if you need that.